# Unplugged External Drive During Write Operation, Now Spins Up But Can not Mount

Tags: mount, data-recovery, usb-drive, external-hdd

I have a 2 TB external USB HDD backup drive. While I was copying some files with nautilus (GUI file explorer) the cord got pulled, but did not come completely out. However, communication was interrupted some how (I'm not sure it ever totally dismounted or totally lost connection). Suffice to say the write failed.

Now I can't seem to mount it again, `dmesg` shows the following after I authorize the device with `usbguard`

```
[  849.092387] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  849.092639] scsi host0: usb-storage 4-2:1.0
[  849.092739] usb 4-2: authorized to connect
[  850.104040] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Drive 2657       1030 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  850.104233] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  850.105371] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[  851.127185] ......
...
[  858.295189] ......not responding...
```

I hear the device spinning then making a rather nasty (but fairly quitet) noise about 3 times

I do not see it in `/media` and I don't even see anything with the label `sda` in `/dev`. I tried plugging the drive in while I was booted into Windows and trying to diagnose it but did not really get anything. I know some people here have said sometimes these devices create a trash file that has a bad write to it or something when unplugging and causes problems. I have seen the file before, but if it is the problem I can't even get too it because I can't even see the folder for the disk!

This message is practically all I have, according too the computer, that it even exists

UPDATE 0:

I do see this in `/sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices` thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574650/usb-device-detection-on-dev-directory-on-linux):

```
T:  Bus=04 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  6 Spd=5000 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 3.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1058 ProdID=2657 Rev=10.30
S:  Manufacturer=Western Digital
S:  Product=Drive 2657
S:  SerialNumber=i removed it from here
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=896mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=1024 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=1024 Ivl=0ms
```

I have identified the place in `/dev` the device is, but it won't mount and it says it is not a block device (I put in `XYZ` in place of the numbers)

`mount: /dev/bus/usb/XYZ/XYZ: /tmp/fix-drive is not a block device.`

UPDATE 1:

I think the hardware is okay, @Brad, below pointed out a way to verify that, if I do a `lsblk` it shows up as an `sda` and it shows up with `lsusb`. I don't know how to get it to show up as a block device under something like `/dev/sda` though (apparently only top level directories in `/dev/` are block devices).

UPDATE 2:

If I leave it for a while, `lsblk` sees it in `/dev/sda` and the folder appears in `/dev/sda`. If I try to mount it I get:
`mount: /tmp/fix-drive: can't read superblock on /dev/sda.`

If I run
`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`
I get
`fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: No such file or directory`

Output of `lsblk` is:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0     0B  0 disk 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  78.3G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   500M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0 392.5G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0   4.4G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p8 259:7    0  1000M  0 part
```

Additional logs from `dmesg` continued from before

```
[10321.876237] .............not responding...
[10514.168814] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[10694.180757] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[10874.188908] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[10874.188970] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[10874.188988] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[10874.189020] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[10874.189043] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[10874.189053] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[11054.200777] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[11054.200829] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[11234.212778] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[11234.212810] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[11234.212815] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[11234.213392] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[11264.324770] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 30s
[12373.688612] /tmp/fix-drive: Can't open blockdev
[12381.408079] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 access beyond end of device
[12381.408086] I/O error, dev sda, sector 2 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x1000 phys_seg 1 prio class 3
[12381.408102] EXT4-fs (sda): unable to read superblock
```

It seems to think the drive is  0b in size

UPDATE 3:

I disassembled the enclosure, which for this model was a messy process which necessitated breaking part of the plastic housing. I took the PCB out and tested continuity between the pins on the connector and their mounting/solder locations on the board. They all seemed to have continuity. To be sure I then tested the continuity between the pins and surface mount resistors which also seemed to have connectivity. They all seemed to have continuity with some surface mount circuit components. Most had resistors that seemed to be assigned too them and had continuity with them.

Anything else I could do to diagnose the board?

UPDATE 3.1:

More complete log (but without attempt to mount)

```
[  138.351630] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[  236.649461] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  236.649467] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[  236.649473] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[  236.649474] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[  236.649478] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  236.649480] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[  236.649482] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[  236.649487] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  236.649920] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[  243.591423] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[  262.021407] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  262.021410] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[  262.021415] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[  262.021416] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[  262.021419] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  262.021421] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[  262.021424] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[  262.021431] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  262.021874] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[  296.295799] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[  524.427980] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[  704.434027] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[  884.451408] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[  884.451448] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  884.451452] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[  884.451455] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[  884.451459] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[  884.451461] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[ 1064.460333] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[ 1064.460378] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[ 1244.464759] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[ 1244.464803] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[ 1244.464809] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1244.465165] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[ 1274.533228] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 30s
```

Comment: post the full output of the following:
`lsblk` and  `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: @Brad I posted it, its weird

Comment: the fact that `sda` is intermittently showing up is definitely suggestive of a hardware fault, as if the hardware was good,  you would _definitely_ see `/dev/sda` *ALL THE TIME*.

i would buy that 3rd party USB-SSD connector and break the physical drive out of the enclosure and then try again at this point.

Comment: you could try something like this to set up a basic monitor in a terminal window that shows the kernel logs -- you might be able to see the intermittent connecting/disconnecting better like this:

`tail -F /var/log/messages | grep sda`

Comment: @Brad Unfortunately No file in `/var/log` called `messages`, any other file I may want too look at in there?

Comment: @Brad I took apart the drive and removed the PCB and tested connectivity between the usb connector pins and surface mount resistors, they all had connectivity. I would expect that if it were a hardware problem, there would have been a mechanics failure between the connector and the board, but I dont see any indication of one. Anything else I could try too look at on the board while it is disassembled?

Comment: interesting -- I'd just try taking the drive out and remove _everything_ else that came within the enclosure out of the loop. You could do so by buying an SSD<->USB connector on Amazon, for example. They cost about 15-20 bucks IIRC. My answer below has a link to the kind of thing I'm talking about

Comment: I am guessing that the PCB (rather than the drive itself) is faulty, but again, process of elimination is needed.

Comment: @Brad 
It may be a bit more complicated and involve replacing the PCB with a compatible one just to test it. It does not have the standard SATA connector: 
https://ibb.co/1RY3yZn
https://ibb.co/rwCfh8Y

The first image is the drive, the white thing encircled is a plug that connects to the PCB, the other circled thing is 4 connecting pads which connect via pressure on the drive.

The second image is the PCB controller and the corresponding port and sort of "springy" connectors are circled, at the bottom is the USB connector I tested

Comment: Also it is an HDD, idk if that makes a difference

Comment: ok - this makes it more tricky, but I think think it would be possible to sidestep the PCB and all the other stuff. The drive will ultimately have a power and a data input which it should be possible to by _separate electronics_ to talk to. Maybe something like this: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Multibao-Adapter-Cable-Converter-Drive/dp/B093H8LTJP/ -- note the bright red cable in those images -- this might fit into the ports your images show. It's hard to picture it properly, but if its a spinning platter (HDD) then it should have a common form factor and a common data interface.

Comment: I am expecting to see something like this: http://www.computerupgradesrepairs.co.uk/hdd.htm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141958/discussion-between-brad-and-the-floating-brain).

Answer (score 1):

Not an easy one, but here are some suggestions:

Forget about trying to mount it until you can first ensure that the hardware (block device) is visible to the kernel. To do this, plug it in *without* mounting it. Then:

- Try `lsblk` and see if you can see the `sda` there.
- Try `lsusb` and see if it shows up there.

If neither of these show the block device (e.g., `sda`), then you might have broken the hardware. Depending on how important it is to recover, you might want to try another cable (did it break?) or, open up the external drive and extract the *actual* drive from the housing. Then try with an alternative USB connector to the one that shipped with the external drive -- something like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Drive-Adapter-Converter-Connector-Auto-sleep/dp/B09K3NB1B6?th=1) perhaps.

Ultimately, you want to be able to see `/dev/sda` first. Once you've gotten to that point, then the challenge around mounting starts... If you can see the device, but it still won't mount, then you could try using a tool called [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/). This will do a very low level copy of the data on the block device onto another drive (e.g., the main drive in the PC, or maybe another external drive). It is clever enough to jump over dodgy sections on the block device, and then provides tools for recovering the files off the drive onto another drive.

Ultimately, a lot of this depends on how valuable the data on the drive is. If you don't care about it, you could just try to reformat the drive with `fdisk` once you can see the block device, otherwise you may be in for a slog.

There are other tools that could be used alongside `ddrescue` that could help recovering certain types of files -- for example `photorec` could be used to recover images from the image the `ddrescue` produces.

Good luck with it!

Comment: Thank you, I will update when I give that a try, I do a `sda` with `lsblk` and I see it in `lsusb` so thats a good sign :) But idk how to get it to show up in `/dev/sda`

Comment: if `lsblk` shows it then it should be in `/dev/sda` as that is what `lsblk` is looking at. try `ls -la /dev/sda` and see what it outputs.

Comment: aaaaand I unplugged it and now its not, will reply again after I can get it to  show up again. Kinda weird I did randomly hear the noise for a usb device connecting on the order of 3 minutes after I connected it

Comment: hrm could be dodgy cable -- if its coming up and down, could be a connection in the cable is not connected properly...

Comment: the cable itself actually looks to be in pretty good condition. Could be a connector, but I kinda doubt it, Im wondering if something triggered it

Comment: looks can be deceiving - it could literally be a micro-fracture in 1 wire in that cable, or the connector, or even the USB port -- its a matter of process of elimination -- so try a different USB port, a different cable (if you have a spare) and work through all the possible variables methodically.

Comment: I just tried a second cord, it has a "funny" connector and it is the only other one I have, but tbh I cant remember if its any good, I may have to order/buy another one for this test. However when I tried it I got the same results. on `lsblk` (no `sda`).

Comment: I just let it sit for a bit again, and it showed up

Comment: if I get it to show up in `/dev/sda` again, even if it tells me its 0 bytes in size, do you think I can run `ddrescue` on it?

Comment: possibly, but it might not even be needed.  you need to approach this systematically. Step 1: make sure the hardware is _consistently_ presented, Step 2: make sure the block device (`/dev/sda`) is okay and visible, Step 3: validate partitions (`/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`) etc, Step 4: attempt to mount it in RO mode.  If, at any point, one of these steps fails, you can then try `dd` or `ddrescue` to copy the _raw_ data off the disk onto another disk, or your local machine - you would create an image file, e.g, `~/sda.img`.

Comment: Then you can run additional tools on that `.img` file rather than on the (possibly faulty) drive to attempt to recover the data. Note that none of this is guaranteed to work.

Comment: i would try to back up `/dev/sda` in _raw_ format as soon as the device presents reliably. You would do this with a `dd` command -- something like `dd if=/dev/sda of=/home/you/sda.img`. If this works, then you can continue your recovery activity on the image file rather than the disk itself, including attempting to mount the `img` file itself (loopback mount).

Comment: When you say in step 2 that the device should be OK and visible I assume that means not saying its at 0 bytes?

How would I try to validate the partitions `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`? Dont see them showing up

Comment: Also as for RO I get these two log messages
```
[  884.451448] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[    0.859262] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 32768k
[  236.649478] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  262.021419] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[ 1064.460378] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
```

Comment: `lsblk` should show the device `/dev/sda` with the correct capacity. Once that happens, and it's not `0` bytes, then you'd need to use some partition management tool to check out the partitions (e.g., `gparted`, `fdisk`, etc)

Comment: those log messages make me suspicious of the PCB (but it could be drive itself) hence my suggestion of bypassing the PCB with an SSD<->USB connector -- it will permit 1 more check in your process of elimination

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Wanted to also ask if this could be the partition table as well?

Comment: Check my other comment about the PCB. I may have to try to find one that is compatible, or even the right shape haha.